Проблема с подключением Cron к проекту на Laravel в Docker
Версия Laravel - 10, PHP - 8.1
Пытаюсь добавить планировщик задач Cron в проект, чтобы можно было реализовать фоновое выполнение задач при помощи планировщика задач Laravel.
При попытке пересборке контейнера для внесения изменений по Cron'y (docker-compose build php) выдает следующее:

chmod: changing permissions of '/etc/cron.d/schedule': Operation not permitted

Если убрать строчку с chmod 0644, то выдает следующее:

cron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied

Прошу подсказать, что я упустил или делаю не так.
Содержимое Dockerfile для контейнера с PHP:
FROM php:8.1-fpm
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nano \
    git \
    curl \
    libpq-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    cron

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --filename=composer --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer

RUN  docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www/html
USER www

ADD schedule /etc/cron.d/schedule
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/schedule
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/schedule
RUN  service cron start

Содержимое файла docker-compose.yml:
version: "3"

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - ./:/var/www/html/
        networks:
            - backend

    php:
        build:
            context: docker/php
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html/
        networks:
            - backend
        depends_on:
            - nginx

    db:
        image: mysql
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USERNAME}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - 127.0.0.1:${DB_PORT_DOCKER}:3306
        networks:
            - backend

networks:
    backend:

Структура проекта:


Думаю вам стоит перенести все от RUN groupadd до USER www ПОСЛЕ RUN  service cron start, потому что команды по крону выполняются с пользователем www и не имеют достаточных прав на то, что вы в них пытаетесь сделать.
